# Weird dots in my mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, noise-reduction

so I'm making a drink scene, but it looks like there are very weird dots around, near the glass. It seems I need to do something to get rid of the white dots.
[image]

Comment: That may be caused by the material of the glass, could you share your node setup?